# Is it possible to show an image in android while downloading it from a server?

Tags: java, android, imageview, imagedownload

I know that WPF and C# have a feature where you can bind a byte-array to an image-view.
Is this feature possible for an android image-view, too? So i can show a picture in bad quality before i have downloaded it completely?

Comment: technically you can with you own function. I dont know If there is an already coded version that you can use.

Comment: assuming it's a progressive JPG you can write a method that displays it when there is sufficient data to do so.

Comment: thank you! I've searched for a definition for this ;) I can search for methods to implement "progressive jpgs" ;)

Comment: Some JPEGs have a thumbnail in the beginning of the file. Even though it's not progressive.